# How to attach icons to ListView for different types of files fetched from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview

I'm implementing a project in which the user can upload and fetch files back from Firebase, these files include image,pdf and maybe doc, doing so I want the fetched files shown in the Listview depending on the type they are to be shown with a icon in the left side, for a pdf file-a pdf icon, for image file-an img icon and so on.

I don't have much experience with ListView and with Android in general, I might figure out how to add a custom icon but not really complete this task, if anyone could give me at least a hint I'd be greatful.
Below I'm showing the code and the app, removing the code parts that don't matter;
[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXWl8.png)

```
 public class Kompjuterike extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kompjuterike);

    displayUpload();
    editPdfName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtuploadfile);
    pdfupload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pdfuploadimg);
    imgupload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imguploadimg);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(databasepath);



}
private void selectPDFFile() {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select pdf file"),1);
}

private void selectIMGFile() {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"select img file"),1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null){
        uploadFile(data.getData());
    }
}


private void uploadFile(Uri data) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading file...");
    progressDialog.show();
    final  StorageReference reference=storageReference.child(databasepath+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    reference.putFile(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText(Kompjuterike.this, "Upload successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    String url = uri.toString();
                    Upload upload = new Upload(editPdfName.getText().toString(), url);
                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    Toast.makeText(Kompjuterike.this, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress=(100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded: "+(int)progress+"%");

        }
    });
}

private void displayUpload(){
    uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    //adding a clicklistener on listview
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //getting the upload
            Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

            //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //getting the database reference
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(databasepath);


    //retrieving upload data from firebase database
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);
            }

            String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
            }

            //displaying it to list
          adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_color,R.id.list_content, uploads);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: from what i know, handling different kind of content is much easier in recyclerview, which is the latest and greatest from google.

Comment: I'll change to it if  it's needed

Comment: You should take a look at custom ArrayAdapters, the one you are using only shows a list with a string in it. with a custom arrayadapter you can define a item_row_layout and put whatever you want in it including icons for the file type

Comment: you need use a custom ArrayAdapter